# integration with different orders

Tags: calculus

We use a lot of different orders to integrate, but I find a lot of difficulties with the order $d\phi$ $d\rho$ $d\theta$. Can you show me how can we know the limits in the following triple integral $\iiint$$\rho^2$$sin\phi$ $d\phi$ $d\rho$ $d\theta$. Usually they sketch a curve that is a fucnction of $\rho$ and $\phi$

the sphere from above $\rho=2$ and the cylinder $x2+y2=1$ from the sides and $xy-plane$ from below

Comment: Over what region are you integrating?

Comment: oh sorry the sphere $\rho$=2 and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\iiint \rho^2\sin \phi \ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta.$

bound by, $\rho \sin \phi = 1$ and $\rho = 2$

$\phi = \arcsin \frac {1}{\rho}$

$2\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac \pi2} \rho^2\sin \phi \ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta + 2\int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^2 \int_0^{\arcsin \frac {1}{\rho}} \rho^2\sin \phi \ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta.$

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but it is not what i've requested!

Comment: Can you reconsider the order of integration? @Doug

Comment: @DanielKamand Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @DougM9 yeah exactly!